# How to change width of master view in splitview controller of ios 10

Tags: ios, xcode, splitview

For collapsing and Expanding the master view of split view, I was using below code.
However, it doesn't work in iOS 10. 
Please suggest how to change the width of `masterview`.

Sample code is below :

**My Code :**

```
-(void)CollapseMasterViewController {
    [ObjSplit setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:77.0] forKey:@"_masterColumnWidth"];
    [ObjSplit.view setNeedsLayout];
}

-(void)ExpandMasterViewController {
    [ObjSplit setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:350.0] forKey:@"_masterColumnWidth"];
    [ObjSplit.view setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Any idea will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set minimumPrimaryColumnWidth, maximumPrimaryColumnWidth?

You can learn more about SplitView configuration in **Getting the Split View Configuration** section in Apple documentation:  https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the relative width of the primary (master) view and the secondary, you can use preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction, which is also described [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller)

Comment: Why did you edit my answer and not the one above? The whole point of showing the full link is that it's the same one.